# Difference between watch endpoints?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm interested in watching a stream of Events from Kubernetes, to determine whether a deployment was successful, or if any of the Pods were unable to be scheduled.

I could call the endpoint `/api/v1/watch/events`, or I could call `/api/v1/events?watch=true`. Is there a difference between those two?  I'm confused about the purpose of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're making `watch` a query param and removing it from the path (legacy form). You should call `/api/v1/events?watch=true`. See more discussions [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8337) if you're interested.